# Golang chan & waitgroup sometime wait a long time?

Tags: go, parallel-processing, channel

I'm new golang. I write a parallel request code but sometimes occur wait a long time. Do you know any reason?

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
    guard := make(chan struct{}, 50)

    for _, li := range results {
       wg.Add(1)
       guard <- struct{}{}
       go func(){
        defer func(){//I'm afraid some panic, so I use defer func, make sure it has done.
            wg.Done()
            <-guard
         }()
          //some biz code 
          //http requests
       }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
```

I try print process number, observer number,  always stuck the last process long time. I don't know the stuck reason. It can be finished, just stuck a long time in the last process.

Comment: Show the code (if any) that calls the Done method on `wg`.  The call to wg.Wait() will bock forever if Done is not called.

Comment: You're calling `wgScore.Done()` instead of `wg.Done()`; is that just a typo? Assuming so, I would instrument your goroutine to ensure the biz code and http requests aren't hanging. Also, remove the `guard` channel and see if that helps -- from this sample of code, it doesn't look needed.

Comment: I see that unparametrized goroutine in loop - I suspect it's a possible source of problem. If your goroutine does not depends on `li` - golang will create only one closure for all cycle, which could be not what you intended. Check your goroutine, make it dependent from `li`, look again